# How is an HTTP POST request made in js?

Tags: javascript, json, post

I am very new to this,  I keep having error "Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function"

````
    button.addEventListener('click', async => {
    try {
    const response = await fetch(
    ' https://student-challenge-api.herokuapp.com/students',
      {
     method: 'post',
               json: true,
            body: {
              name: '',
              last_name: ' '
            
             },
          }
        );
        
        console.log('Completed!', response);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Error: ${err}`);
      }
    }); ```
````

Comment: `async =>` should be `async () =>`

Comment: Change `async => {` to `async () => {`

Comment: now I am getting this error, "" Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null""

Comment: @Ivar, please advise

Comment: @natasha It means that `button` is `null` and so it probably couldn't be found. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element